# Clearing DbProviderFactories in App.config

Tags: .net, app-config, machine.config, dbproviderfactories

I have an App.config where I would like to replace the provider specified in machine.config with a different version of the provider.  I have tried removing the provider by name with `remove` and have now tried removing them *all* with `clear`.

This seems to have no effect: The connection string is still loading the provider specified in `machine.config`. For example, when use the configuration below, I expect the application *not* to find my provider.

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <clear />
  </system.data>
```

Further, specifying a different name or trying to override the same name; also has no effect.

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <clear />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="testprovider" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
                       type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.3.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot remove the provider by "name". You must remove it with its "invariant" name instead.

Example:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.3.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```